# Jquery Hover Out - Adding Timeout Breaks Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to update my tooltip jquery code so that when the user moves the mouse off the tooltip icon the tooltip delays while they copy the text. I tried adding this timeout which works the first time the icon is clicked but when the icon is clicked again the tooltip displays blank. If I remove the timeout code it works.

Tooltip Works On First Click:

[image: Tooltip Working Example]

Tooltip Appears Blank On Second Click:

[image: Tooltip Not Working]

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
var hoverTimeout;
// Tooltip only Text
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {
    // Hover over code
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .text(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}, function () {
    // Hover out code
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }, 5000);
}).click(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem: `$(this)` in your first function refers to `Object [ div.masterTooltip ]` (I tested with a single div because you didn't include any HTML in your question), but `$(this)` in your second function refers to `Object [ Window ]`. That leads to `data('tipText')` being undefined in the second function, so no title attribute is inserted, which gives you an empty tooltip after the first time the function was executed.

This code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var hoverTimeout;
// Tooltip only Text
var masterTooltip = $('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {
    // Hover over code
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .text(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}, function () {
    // Hover out code
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(masterTooltip).attr('title', $(masterTooltip).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }, 5000);
}).click(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue but if you open multiple tooltips before the delay is up they will overlap each other. Is there a way to close the other open tooltip on click if it hasn't expired yet?

Comment: I think there's no simple solution to this as long as you select the tooltips by class name exclusively, because that way you can only remove all of them. Using the class selector, you would have to check for an existing tooltip first, remove it, and then create the new tooltip.